# NSPredicate weird crash with NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to get a CoreData entity based on her name, to do that a created a method, that accepts a name parameter (NSString), so this is the method:

```
-(void)pegarCategoryByName:(NSString *)catName {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Category Name: %@", catName);
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categorias" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoria == '%@'", catName];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
   // [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext]executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects.count > 0) {

        _categoriaAtual = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Category not Found");
    }


}
```

So lets say i call somewhere in my code:

```
[self pegarCategoryByName:@"Songs"];
```

When i run i get the NSLog: Category Name Songs, Category not Found and them the App crashes.

The weird part is, if i change the NSPredicate on pegarCategoryName to not use the NSString passed, here's and example:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoria == 'Songs'"];
```

Everything works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not enclose the `%@` placeholder in the predicate format in quotation marks:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoria == %@", catName];
```

Comment: i just fell really stupid right now, i've being struggling with this for at least 30 minutes, and it never occur to me, to do that. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

`catName` is *already* a string; you don't need to surround it with quotes, it would be the same as:

```
categoria == '@"Songs"'
```

so remove them:

```
@"categoria == %@"
```